# As/400 Library Woes

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, ibm-midrange

I saw few answered AS/400 questions out there, but I hope I can be one of the lucky few whose question gets answered.

So I have crystal reports that run queries on multiple AS/400 files through an ODBC connection. Problem i am facing is that the reports are only trying to access records that are in the default file listed in the ODBC and it does not traverse the list of libraries (which incidentally has most of the records).

How can I go about troubleshooting this error, or is there some option that I may have failed to enable in order to have the ODBC traverse the list as opposed to only view the default Library?

Comment: I checked the last 50 questions tagged `ibm-midrange`.  Of those, only 8 were unanswered.  So in that sample we handle  Whether the poster comes back and marks one of them accepted, that we can't help.  Often we post comments asking questions for more information to understand how to answer the question properly.  Sometimes we don't get a response back.  Sometimes the comment may have answered the question.  Sometimes people ask questions that are for an obscure combination of subjects where few would know anything.  So if you check the pages, you'll see we do have a pretty good track record.

Comment: Of course there are also people who ask questions that are off topic for this site.  See the [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for a description of what stackoverflow is for.  Some questions we get here are not actually programming questions. Some are asking for other help, like software settings, and often belong on [super user](http://superuser.com) or another of the [many StackExchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid).  That's ok.  We (usually) answer them anyway.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the Crystal Reports. After enabling the option to verify table on each load, the reports worked perfectly without alluding to the a fore mentioned error.

Answer (score 3):

ODBC allows for the library list.  Enable system naming instead of SQL naming.  IBM [technical document 9951625](http://www-912.ibm.com/s_dir/slkbase.NSF/0/2554db904e5a601b862565c2007cc4b8) has ODBC information that might be helpful.

I think the bigger problem is to make Crystal Reports stop fully qualifying SQL statements.  I never worked that out.

Comment: The problem, I found out, was not with the ODBC, it was with the Crystal Report. Of 20 like reports, these three apparently kept on seeing anamolies with the DB2 files they were to access and kept on failing to load and blamed it on the ODBC.